# Access Django Test Database

Tags: python, django, database, unit-testing, django-models

I have an API running on Heroku and would like to be able to test it using the test database. My problem I have is that the TestCase setUp(self) method adds the data to an automatically created test database. Then my tests send a POST request to the locally running version of itself. That code then is just using the regular default database instead of the test database the tests are running in.

Here's some code and what I've tried.

In my main settings.py I have named my database like so

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'theOneTrueDB',
    }
}
```

And I read here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) that

> The default test database names are created by prepending test_ to the value of each NAME in DATABASES.

So I figured in my views file for one of my apps I could just do
Tenant.objects.using('test_theOneTrueDB').all() and that would work but it says

> django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection test_theOneTrueDB doesn't exist

I have also tried

```
Tenant.objects.using('test_default')
```

and many other things. I am lost. I would also be okay with setting up another database and then using that in the setup with

```
Tenant.objects.save(using='theOneTrueDBTest)
```

or something like that.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I know have my settings looking like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'theOneTrueDB',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    },
    'other': {
        'NAME': 'theOneTrueTest',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

but then if I try to save to the other database like this

```
tempPM.save(using='other')
```

Then I get this error

> AssertionError: Database queries to 'other' are not allowed in this test. Add 'other' to API.tests.TenantLogin.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access the test database directly. It will be used by default and you don't need to worry about it.

By default for sqlite3 backend will be used in-memory database, with the name like this `file:memorydb_default?mode=memory&cache=shared`, 
you can examine the settings while tests are running via:

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.DATABASES)
```

Comment: See details in source for [sqlite3 backend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py#L20).

Comment: If I use `--keepdb` and I want to check the DB with a DBMS application, how would I do it?